# Is it possible to replace all the functionality of performance counter by having Event counter class?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-core

I have created a class which inherits performance counter class and uses all its functionality , But after going through the documentation of EventCounters which says that it is cross platform alternative of Performance counter, I think of replacing performance counter class with event counter class , but i see some limitations such as

```
Performance counter has Decrement method but Event counter does not have this method.
I can also see both the classes contains lots of method and property differences
```

So my question is, Is it possible to replace all the functionality of performance counter by having Event counter class ?

Comment: No, because perf counters are an extremely lightweight feature provided by the OS itself - and only work on Windows. Besides, EventCounters are the *old* API. In .NET 6 [System.Diagnostics.Metrics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/metrics-instrumentation) was introduced which, apart from local perf monitoring, integrates directly with OpenTelemetry, allowing distributed metrics collection from multiple services. The various perf APIs are compared in [Comparing Metrics APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/compare-metric-apis)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the workflow. What is currently done with the performance counter data? Because afaik event counter data is not available in for example tools like the windows performance monitor.

> Performance counter has Decrement method but Event counter does not have this method

Other that that, I think it shouldn't be a problem. Of the available counters as described in [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/event-counters#eventcounter-api-overview) both the `EventCounter` and the `PollingCounter` can track individual values so increments and decrements can be tracked.

Do mind that `EventCounter` is replaced by the `Meter` class as shown [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/metrics-instrumentation#create-a-custom-metric). To see a list of differences between the several options take a look at [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/compare-metric-apis). In short, the advantages of using the new metric api using `Meter` are:

- Histograms and percentiles
- Multi-dimensional metrics
- Strongly typed high-performance listener API
- Multiple simultaneous listeners
- Listener access to unaggregated measurements

> I can also see both the classes contains lots of method and property differences

Sure, you will need to refactor the code as it is not a 1-on-1 replacement.

In the end, whether you can replace them or not is a different question than how the data is used. To capture .net counters output you can use a tool like [dotnet-counters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/dotnet-counters).